# Make Score History in Array Field Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to make history score in Array

I try u make score in array like this

[this my firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiFQe.png)

And this is my code

```
  String uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
  muridref.document(uid).update("nilai", FieldValue.arrayUnion(skortampil));
```

When I get the same score the array field doesn't make new Array data,
without see data there or not in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation [Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) about this behavior:

> If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. **arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present**.

Considering that, it's working as expected, since it's not adding values that are equal. So, this means that you won't be able to add values that are equal using the method `arrayUnion()` directly.

This other question from the Community - accessible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110491/firestore-doesnt-store-two-identical-values-while-updating-an-array/56110521) - indicates that for you to achieve this goal, you will need to read all the values from the array in your client side, update your values in the array outside the database and then, writing/updating it back in the database.

Let me know if the information helped you!