# How do I write a default arraylist in firestore field by the help of Model Class?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a modal class PlayerDetails:

```
public class PlayerDetails{
    @ServerTimestamp
    Date regDate;
    boolean hasPlayed;
    ArrayList<Integer> optionSkipped;

    PlayerDetails();

    PlayerDetails(Date regDate, boolean hasPlayed , ArrayList<Integer> optionSkipped){
            this.regDate = regDate;
            this.hasPlayed = hasPlayed;
            this.optionSkipped = optionSkipped;

     }
}
```

I want to store `[-1,-1,-1,-1]` as default of `optionSkipped` in firestore document field.
Like this[image]

I present in Firstore database my field optionSkipped is `null`

I am inserting data in Firstore like this:

```
PlayerDetails details=new PlayerDetails(null,false,null);
databaserefrence.collection("game")
.document("game1")
.set(details)
.addOnCompleteListener
..........................
............etc
```

After adding [-1,-1,-1,-1] ArrayList in Firestore.

I want to update the same array later, like this perhaps [0,0,-1,-1].

Comment: Can you add error log in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the following object using:

```
PlayerDetails details=new PlayerDetails(null,false,null);
```

It means that you let Firebase servers assign the `regDate` field [a Firestore timestamp value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/how-to-add-a-timestamp-in-firestore-with-android/48475027#48475027), for the `hasPlayed` field you assign the value of `false`, and for the `optionSkipped` you assign null.

If you want your `optionSkipped` field to hold for example an array with four elements:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Then you should pass a list as the last argument to the constructor when you create an object of class:

```
List<Integer> optionSkipped = Arrays.asList(-1, -1, -1, -1);    
PlayerDetails details=new PlayerDetails(null,false,optionSkipped);
```

Right after that, the document will look like this:

```
$docId
 |
 --- regDate: March 14, 2023...
 |
 --- hasPlayed: false
 |
 --- optionSkipped: [-1, -1, -1, -1]
```

If you later want to update the `optionSkipped` array with other values using [FieldValue#arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayUnion(java.lang.Object...)), then please note that according to the official documentation for [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

> You can use `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements. `arrayUnion()` adds elements to an array but only elements **not** already present. `arrayRemove()` removes all instances of each given element.

As I see in your question, you need to add duplicate elements as in the following example:

```
[0, 0, -1, -1]
```

So to solve this, I recommend you check my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore doesn't store two identical values while updating an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110491/firestore-doesnt-store-two-identical-values-while-updating-an-array)